# Index of element in Numpy array 1

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am doing work on parallelization .and I have numpy array in between.
I want to check the index of numpy array
for example :

pos is a ndarray and its value is

```
 pos :

 ndarray[[    0.    44.  2367.]
         [    0.    73.  2301.]
         [    0.    38.  2304.]
         [    0.    35.  2349.]
         [    0.     6.     0.]
         [    0.    43.  2319.]
         [    0.    95.  2381.]
         [    0.   189.     3.]
         [    0.     0.  2339.]
         [    0.    22.  2335.]
         [    0.    44.  2345.]
         [    0.    44.  2345.]
         [    0.    52.  2348.]
         [    0.    50.  2348.]]

 dtype :float64

 max : 2381.0
 min :0.0

 Shape = {tuple}(14, 3)

 size :42
```

I want to consider for my calculation only 2nd position of pos `ndarray` for example `2367,2301,2304`...etc.
so how can I indexing them and how can I sort 2nd position value only? means if 2nd position of array is 3,4,2,1 then I want 2nd position is  1,2,3,4  like that..
give me suggestion..

Comment: numpy basic documentation... it is the first page...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to the column with index 2 (i.e. the rightmost column) of the array, you can just do

`pos[:,2]`

If you want to sort (in place) the pos array by the second column, you can do:

`pos[:,2].sort()`

Comment: Be careful with `pos[:,2].sort()`.  It sorts *only* one column in place, and leaves the other columns untouched.  It does not sort the full array `pos`.

Comment: and I also wanted to count pos[i][:,2]< 0 to 25 ; then pos[i][:,2]<25 to 50 and i want to make 12 for loop for counting only 2nd position of pos array and then made it independent and want to run this 12 for loops parallel. so give me suggestion

Comment: @Warren Weckesser but its give None only not printing result ..why??

Comment: The sort method modifies the array "in place", and returns None.  So just call the method, and then `print(pos)`.